# FTP upload with monomac

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, mono, monomac

is it possible to write a program that uploads files to a FTP by using mono development tools and a monomac project? is FTP upload supported by the framework or will i have to invent something painfully complex, way beyond my skills?

thanks

Comment: Why cannot you search? http://www.dijksterhuis.org/webclient-class-upload-download-ftp-files/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Lots** of choice.

Mono itself (it's framework) includes `WebClient` (like Lex commented) and [FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) (and FtpWebResponse). One known limitation is that is does not support FTP+SSL (ftps://). That's likely the easiest option as it does not require any additional dependency and you'll find/google a lot of code samples using those classes.

If that does not fit your need (e.g. SSL support) then there are also several .NET libraries, commercial or open source, support FTP (and other protocols) included (or not) in the base class library.

MonoMac offers bindings to OSX API, including a lot of networking classes - but I've never seen (nor really looked) something for FTP **upload** (but downloads can be done based on the URL).

Finally you can create (or find) .NET bindings to Objective-C libraries that supports FTP. See this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7022959/220643) for some links on Objective-C libraries (that you could bind).